# How to Customise the Log file generated in the robot Framework Report

Tags: robotframework

I want only test scenarios in the Log file of the report generated in the Robot Framework but while clicking upon the Test Scenarios the test scripts is getting expanded and the Test steps are clearly visible how can stop this issue
[image: Desired]

I have attached the screenshots I want to achieve this

But I am getting this type of Log Report [image: current]

Answer (score 0):

In Robot Framework userguide there is an entire section dedicated to this functionality: [Removing and Flattening Keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#removing-and-flattening-keywords). In your case I think that the `--removekeywords all` or the `--removekeywords passed` should be of particular interest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the issue is when we are clicking in the Test case scenario the test step are clearly visible for e.g in the second screenshot if you observe  if i click on the '+' in the test scenario it is getting expended and the test steps are visible i want to avoid this

Comment: By using the above argument your keywords will nog longer feature in the log.

Comment: But Sir the steps are clearly visible i want to eliminate this only test scenerios i wnat