# How to Customize Test Report in Robot Framework?

Tags: html, python-2.7, output, report, robotframework

[image]

[image]

i am new to this robotframework...i want to know whether there is a possiblity of customizing the outputfiles...for example in log.html i want only Test Scenario not the steps ....AS in the picture I want to disable the "Expand Button"(+). So whenever anyone open the output file in browser it should only display the TEST case.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536074/how-to-customise-the-log-file-generated-in-the-robot-framework-report

Answer (score 0):

Edit the log.html file, and remove the JavaScript code.